# What on premises container management solutions are there?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, mesosphere, docker-swarm

I've been tasked with evaluating container management solutions. I'm aware there is a large number or options, but we need production ready, on premises solution. What are the options?

Comment: I left a quick answer below. If you want a more elaborate one, happy to share the draft of my upcoming (free) O'Reilly minibook, see https://twitter.com/mhausenblas/status/662328688243970048 … just ping me via michael DOT hausenblas AT gmail DOT com.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In descending order, from most mature and battle-tested at scale to less so:

- [Marathon](https://mesosphere.github.io/marathon/docs/native-docker.html), a Apache Mesos framework
- [Kubernetes](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/)
- [Docker Swarm](http://blog.docker.com/2015/11/swarm-1-0/)
- HashiCorp's [Nomad](https://www.nomadproject.io/)

Comment: Nomad is not a container management service, but rather cluster management service. It can be integrated with docker using so called drivers however not necessarily.

Comment: Same is true for Marathon.